# Unix backup script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, backup

I am trying to learn scripting in Ubuntu.

I need to backup files created by a specific user in a folder where other users store there files. It needs to be compressed into a tar file with the file tree intact.

**Edit:** How do I find those files created by a user and then compressing them into a tar file with all the direcories and subdirectories

```
FILENAME=user_archive.tar
DESDIR=/home/user
FILES=find /shared -type d -user user * tar -rvf $DESDIR/$FILENAME
tar -jcvf $DESDIR/$FILENAME
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Cyrus and using [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/), you keep the following error

> To assign the output of a command, use var=$(cmd)

Then you get some errors to correct and here a working script

```
FILENAME=user_archive.tar
DESDIR=/home/user
FILES=$(find /shared -type d -user user)
tar -jcvf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $FILES
```